# PHP- Filter an Array of Associative Array

Tags: php

All. I am sure that someone may have asked similar thing but I failed to find the related thread.
I have the following array of associative array

May I know how I can extract an array of data with only `[type] => Beverage` ?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [prod_name] => Coffee 
        [type] => Beverage 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [prod_name] => Vegetable 
        [type] => Food 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [prod_name] => Orange Juice 
        [type] => Beverage 
    )
)
```

I have looked at the function array filter but still cannot figure the answer out. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with `array_filter`:

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'prod_name' => 'Coffee', 'type' => 'Beverage'],
    ['id' => 2, 'prod_name' => 'Vegetables', 'type' => 'Food'],
    ['id' => 3, 'prod_name' => 'Orange Juice', 'type' => 'Beverage'],
];

$output = array_filter($data, function ($record) {
    if ($record['type'] == 'Beverage')
        return $record;
});

var_dump($output);
```

Yields:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["prod_name"]=>
    string(6) "Coffee"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "Beverage"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["prod_name"]=>
    string(12) "Orange Juice"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "Beverage"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just `return $record['type'] == 'Beverage'` would do. _"If the callback function returns true, thecurrent value from array is returned into the result array."_ The modern short version for a one-op filter would be, `$output = array_filter($data, fn($record) => $record['type'] == 'Beverage');`.

Comment: Indeed it could be more terse, I think the more verbose syntax is good for somebody learning to understand.

Comment: That it is, just dropped in the option. Still, on the return value, `array_filter` only cares about a boolean. A strict comparison of `$record['type'] === 'Beverage'` is `true`. Any string value is "truish" and will simply be coerced to `true`. No need for that.